# How to get value textarea in tinymce on form modal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've try to make a form edit with bootstrap modal and tinymce inside the form, when i clicked edit data. the data is not showing in tinymce, see the image,
[form modal with tinymce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ynzoh.png)

here is my code

```
function edit(id){

save_method = "update";
$('#form')[0].reset();
$('.form-body').removeClass('has-error');
$('.help-block').empty();

$.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo site_url("profil/ajax_edit/")?>/'+id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('[name="profil_id"]').val(data.profil_id);
            $('[name="post_nama"]').val(data.nama);
            $('[name="post_jk"]').val(data.jenis_kelamin);
            $('[name="post_date"]').val(data.tanggal_lahir);
            $('[name="post_kota"]').val(data.id_kota);
            $('[name="post_alamat"]').val(data.alamat);
            $('[name="post_email"]').val(data.email);
            $('[name="post_telepon"]').val(data.telepon);
        if (data.profil_status == 'active'){
            $(':radio[name=post_status][value="active"]').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(':radio[name=post_status][value="notactive"]').prop('checked', true);
        }   

        if(data.photo){
            $('#photoPreview').html('<img src="'+base_url+'upload/profil/'+data.photo+'" width="75" height="50">');
        }
            $('#modal_form').modal('show');
            $('.modal-title').text('Edit Profile');

        },
         error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error get data from ajax');
    }

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `php` inside of `js`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo site_url("profil/ajax_edit/")?>/'+id,
```

Add your path properly.

Comment: i think is not the problem sir

Comment: Really? Can you actually console.log(data) inside of success: function(data) and get the right result?